# phpMyAdmin automatically logins in without requesting my login details

Tags: mysql, authentication, phpmyadmin, webserver, controlpanel

I have WAMP server installed for some time now and it has always asked me for my username and password whenever I load phpMyAdmin from the WAMP control panel. Recently, I changed the `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';` in the config.inc.php to `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'NO';` in the hope that it fixed a database connection problem I was having (it didn't btw) so I tried to change it back by removing the 'NO' but once I did that whenever I load up phpMyAdmin, it automatically logins me in bypassing the login page. How do I fix it where it starts asking me again for my login details?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Change/add this parameter in `config.inc.php` to use cookie, then phpMyAdmin will throw you a login dialog

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

Then this line shoiuld not be set to `'NO'` as this is the field that could contain the hardcoded password

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

Maybe you ment to change

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

Comment: it already has the auth_type parameter set to cookie

Comment: If that does not work, you had better show me the complete `config.inc.php` file so we can search for the error